# facebook photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

mypermission are

$par['req_perms'] = "publish_stream,
                    offline_access,
                    user_status,
                    user_photos,
                    user_videos,
                    user_photo_video_tags,
                    read_stream,
                    user_likes,
                    user_events,
                    email,
                    user_groups";

i try to get facebook photos calling method

$photos = $facebook->api('/'.'userid'.'/photos');

but i get empty array, what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing at `/userid/photos`.

Comment: userid need to replace by "id of facebook user"

@FRKT Did u try github example

"grph.facebook.." url is bing inside the method

Comment: @kasun: You're not making any sense.

Comment: Solution for this we need to get album first and then using album id we need to get photos, but somehow there should be a way to get photos directly